# Need to filter child eloquent relationship by grandparent value

Tags: php, eloquent

I have the following relationships
`Contact -> belongsToMany -> Person -> hasMany -> Field Values`

```
class Contact extends Model {
    public function people()
    {
         return $this->belongsToMany(Person::class)
    }
}
```

```
class Person extends Model {
    public function field_values()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(FieldValue::class)
    }
}
```

The issue is that field values can be contact specific. For example, person Z works for two contacts, A and B, and earns a different salary with each company. Person Z will have two field values for salary, one with contact_id A and another with contact_id B

When I select `Contact::with(['people','people.field_values'])`, I want to return the contacts, people and their field values. If I select contact A and B, then each contact should have a copy of person Z, but person Z within contact A should only have the field values that relate to contact A, and the goes same for contact B

At the moment I'm getting all the field values for Person Z in both contact A and contact B